# Ng-grid remove duplicates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, ng-grid

In my Ng-grid cell,i have applied this cell template. i'm getting data but with duplicated regionName.

```
<select ng-cell-input
    ng-options="l.RegionID as l.RegionName for l in regionActivities"
    ng-class="'colt' + $index" ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input='COL_FIELD' ng-change="activityRegionChange(row)" ng-show='!isRoomRequestInProgress'></select>
```

{{COL_FIELD}}

is there any way to prevent duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is building or reusing a [unique filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)

```
<select ng-cell-input
ng-options="l.RegionID as l.RegionName for l in regionActivities | unique:'RegionName'"
ng-class="'colt' + $index" ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input='COL_FIELD' ng-change="activityRegionChange(row)" ng-show='!isRoomRequestInProgress'></select>
```